# Using HTML5 Database API

Tags: html, storage, local-storage

I'm developing a web-app using `phonegap/cordova 2.2` and want to store data in sql type database but it seems that as **html5** is not yet documented and there are three competing approaches for saving serious amounts of data, its confusing about which approach should i use. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also check out my own library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db/wiki/Home . The library supports iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8.

### Goal

Beautiful database API for secure, robust, high-performance, maintainable, large-scale javascript web app.

### Features

- Support IndexedDB, WebSQL and WebStorage storage mechanisms.
- Support all features of asynchronous IndexedDB API.
- Well tested closure library module.
- Fixed schema, auto versioning, on-the-fly schema generation while maintaining multiple connections (on tabs, or worker).
- Low-level cursor iteration, high level query
- Each method call is an atomic transaction, while supporting transaction and advance transaction workflow.
- We adopt strict javascript coding pattern: no global, no eval, no error globbing, parameterized query, all public methods and constructors are strongly type, this is this, coding error throw error.
- JQuery plugin available (see download section).

### Basic usage

```
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('db name');
db.put('store1', {test: 'Hello World!'}, 123);
db.get('store1', 123).done(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

### Documentations

- [User Guide](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/getting-started.html)
- [API Reference](http://dev.yathit.com/api-reference/ydn-db/storage.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can check storage document here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

For query syntax, you can check at sqlite.org

HTML5 DB work smoothly on iOS and Android, but there some problems in Blackberry.
Window Phone 7 does not support HTML5 DB.

You can check PhoneGap Plugins for SQLite at:

https://github.com/brodyspark/PhoneGap-sqlitePlugin-iOS

https://github.com/brodyspark/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-Android

https://github.com/marcucio/Cordova-WP-SqlitePlugin (WP8+)

Answer (score 1):

If you desire a relational database option, but are concerned with WebSQL (the standard was abandoned and not implemented in many browsers), another excellent option is: [SequelSphere](http://www.sequelsphere.com)

It is a 100% HTML5/JavaScript Relational Database that works cross-browser and uses either IndexedDB or local storage to persist it's data. In PhoneGap/Cordova it would use IndexedDB, thereby giving you the ability to store "serious amounts" of data in a relational method allowing for SQL queries. It is it's own database engine, and doesn't rely upon the built-in (WebSQL) relational databases. As such, it will also work across all browsers and platforms should you want to port your app elsewhere.

It's API is readily available on the website at:

- Here is the API:  [SequelSphere API](http://www.sequelsphere.com/dbdocs/api-documentation/)
- Documentation on the basics:  [SequelSphere Basic](http://www.sequelsphere.com/how-it-works/code-sample/)
- SequelSphere Documentation on "Local Storage" support: Local
  [Data Storage and Persistence](http://www.sequelsphere.com/dbdocs/local-data-storage/)